# How to catch OSError?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

This post request here, I am trying to handle OSError. But below written try-catch blocks, or the onError, catchError functions are doing no good. Can I get some inputs on how to handle these types of errors?

```
    // BELOW POST REQUEST
    try {
    Response response = await post(Uri.parse(
            "$postgToken?accessToken=${googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken}"))
        .catchError((e) {
      log("$e");
    });
    
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'network_error') {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(
        content: Text("Please check your network connection"),
      ),
    );
  } else {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(
        content: Text("Some error occoured"),
      ),
    );
  }
} on SocketException catch (e) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        actions: [
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                  SystemNavigator.pop();
                } else {
                  exit(0);
                }
              },
              child: Text('Exit')),
        ],
        content:
            Text("Please check your internet connection and try again"),
      );
    },
  );
} on OSError catch (e) {
  log("$e");
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        actions: [
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                  SystemNavigator.pop();
                } else {
                  exit(0);
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Try Again')),
        ],
        content: const Text("Error connecting to the server"),
      );
    },
  );
  _googleSignIn.disconnect();
  _googleSignIn.signOut();
}
```

}

I have handled other errors above like PlatformException and SocketException. But am not able to handle this one.

Comment: Exactly what is the error?  What is the stacktrace?  Are you sure it's being thrown from within that `try` block?  Given that your `try` block uses `.catchError` and swallows all exceptions, it seems unlikely it's being thrown from there.

Comment: I am running a server locally on docker. The post request is being made to that local server. But for testing, I didn't run the server. So the post request isn't being made and error is popping up.

Comment: message: "Connection timed out"
osError: OSError (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110)
address: _InternetAddress (InternetAddress('10.0.2.2', IPv4))
runtimeType: Type (SocketException)